# Query for Users who have granted login access

Tags: grant-login-access, grant-login

Is it possible to query for Users who have granted me login access from a given Org?

Comment: Hey Kyle, I am 99.99% sure this particular ask is not possible, but maybe if the question is framed differently, it could help with a broader solution. Whats the problem you're trying to solve?